# Put List in sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I made class `Employee` and I also made `List<Employee>` which accept object from the the class.

I put three objects in that list and I want to save them after close the app. I try to use `SharedPreferences` to put  the list but it seem that `SharedPreferences` does not accept to put list in it. How can I do it?

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences data = this.getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    // I cant use editor to put list<Employee>



}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: What you jave tried?

Comment: it will help  u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: i edit my question >>> see it

Comment: it is better to use à sqlitedatabase

Answer (score 1):

You can't store a list of objects in sharedPrefs, but you can store a Set of String:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Your list of epmloyees
    List<Employee> someList;
    // The Set to store the converted objects
    Set<String> objects = new HashSet<String>();

    // Convert each Object into a JSON-String
    for (Employee e : someList) {
        objects.add(new Gson().toJson(e));
    }

    SharedPreferences data = this.getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();

    // Store the Set of JSON-String into the sharedPrefs
    editor.putStringSet("key", objects);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences data = this.getSharedPreferences("data",MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Empty list of employees
    List<Employee> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Set of JSON-Strings from the sharedPrefs
    Set<String> objects = data.getStringSet("key", null);

    // Convert each JSON-String into an Object of Employee
    for (String s : objects) {
        objects.add(new Gson().fromJson(s, Employee.class);
    }         

}
```

In order to store your custom objects as a string, you need to serialize them (for example as json) and save this string. On loading the value you need to deserialize them.

You can read this [guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for advanced help on how to serialize Objects into JSON.

Comment: my aim is to save the list of object after close the programm

Comment: yeah thats how you do it, just use this in your onPause() method.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly the answer using shared preferences but thought it may help

Serialize an object and pass it around :

I use the code below and then write a class that will have any variables rather than shared preferences that is not dependable.

```
public class SharedVariables {

public static <S extends Serializable> void writeObject(
        final Context context, String key, S serializableObject) {

    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(key, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        objectOut.writeObject(serializableObject);
        fileOut.getFD().sync();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SharedVariable", e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (objectOut != null) {
            try {
                objectOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("SharedVariable", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static <S extends Serializable> S readObject(
        final Context context, String key, Class<S> serializableClass) {

    ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(key);
        objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        final Object object = objectIn.readObject();
        return serializableClass.cast(object);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SharedVariable", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("SharedVariable", e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (objectIn != null) {
            try {
                objectIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("SharedVariable", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Then example class:

```
public class Timestamps implements Serializable {

private float timestampServer;

public float getTimestampServer() {
    return timestampServer;
}

public void setTimestampServer(float timestampServer) {
    this.timestampServer = timestampServer;
}
```

}

Then in activity:

```
SharedVariables.writeObject(getApplicationContext(), "Timestamps", timestampsData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Shared Preferences takes only string so you can't keep an object into shared preferences. This problem comes if you want to send Employee object from one activity to another activity
```

This is how i solved it:
Add the following library to your project(take the latest one):

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
```

You convert the `Employee` object to string and store in shared preferences:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(employeeObject);
//store this string in shared preferences and next time when you come back
//get string from shared preferences and convert this back to object
Gson gson = new Gson();
Employee example = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Employee.class);
```

Comment below if you have doubts